# Display options values from 2 dropdown menus in Textbox?

Tags: javascript, select, drop-down-menu, textbox, hashmap

I have an array in Javascript

```
var values = [1, 2, 0.1, 1, 3, .2, 2, 3,.3];
```

and another array that shows the text for each int:

```
var names = [1, 'X', 2, 'Y', 3, 'Z'];
```

I already converted this to a hash map like this:

```
hash = {(1,2): 0.1, (1,3): .2, (2,3): .3}
```

I needed to convert `values` to a `hash` because I have 2 dropdown menus and a textbox that displays a value depending on the 2 values the user chooses from the dropdown menus

This is what I have created so far: https://plnkr.co/edit/g89r9TdIzJFxc3r5u8h9?p=preview

However, I now want the corresponding letter value from the `names` array to show in the textbox. As can be seen in the link, `Z` appears in the 1st and 3rd textboxes, instead of `X` for each. I want the 1st and 3rd textboxes to show the letters from the 2 dropdown menus. So if the 1st choice is `X` and the 2nd `Y`, then the 1st textbox should show `X` and the 3rd textbox should show `Y`

How do I do this?

Comment: So, you want the 1st txtbox = 1drpdown and 3rd txtbox = 2drpdown. Am i right? if so why not just copy the value on change event using javscript

Comment: This: `{(1,2): 0.1}` doesn't make sense. You could do `{"1,2": 0.1}` or ``{"(1,2)": 0.1}``, but you can't have `(1,2)` as on object property key name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the specific question, it looks like the problem is happening inside the following block of code:

```
$('#selectNumber1').on('change', function(){
        firstValue = $(el).text();
        $('#nm1').val(firstValue);
});
$('#selectNumber2').on('change', function(){
        secondValue = $(el2).text();
        $('#nm2').val(secondValue);
});
```

The variables `el` and `el2` are created a little further up the script, in two loops that create the select options. When the first loop completes, `el` is equal to the last option that the loop created - Z. When the second loop completes, `el2` is equal to the last option that that loop created - also Z.

Since `el` and `el2` are not changed, they will always point to the Z option in the first dropdown and the Z option in the second dropdown, respectively.

To solve this, you just need to grab the label of the option that is currently selected. You can do this using some helpful jQuery methods:

```
firstValue = $("#selectNumber1").find(":selected").text(); //For the first dropdown's selected label
secondValue = $("#selectNumber2").find(":selected").text(); //For the second dropdown's selected label
```

Here's an explanation of what's happening:

1. `$("#selectNumber1")` - jQuery will attempt to find the element with an ID of "selectNumber1";
2. `.find(":selected")` - With the element(s) that jQuery finds in step 1, find the child(ren) that have the "selected" attribute (find the option that is selected); and
3. `.text()` - Return the inner text of the first element found in step 2.

Putting it all together, you will end up with this:

```
$('#selectNumber1').on('change', function(){
        firstValue = $("#selectNumber1").find(":selected").text();
        $('#nm1').val(firstValue);
});
$('#selectNumber2').on('change', function(){
        secondValue = $("#selectNumber2").find(":selected").text();
        $('#nm2').val(secondValue);
});
```

That should work just fine for you, but all that being said, I would consider doing some major clean up and simplification of your code. The data structure you have is difficult to work with (if you have no choice because this is how data is being given to you, I understand), variables are defined and redefined making it tricky to follow, and there's some use of jQuery in some places and straight JS in others, which can also be hard to follow.

For data structure, it might be much easier for you if your data looked something more like this:

```
    var data = {
        x: {
            y: 0.1,
            z: 0.2
        },
        y: {
            x: 0.9,
            z: 0.3
        },
        z: {
            x: 0.8,
            y: 0.7
        }
    }
```

If your data was in a matrix like this, then you could reference data values as `data.x.y` for when x is selected first and y second, versus `data.y.x` for when the opposite is the case. If you needed to get at those properties as variables, say var first = "x" and var second = "y", then you could use data[first][second].

The nested properties make life a little easier in this case.

That's just food for thought, many ways to accomplish the task.

Hope this helps!

Helpful links:
https://api.jquery.com/find/
https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Thanks for your help! As for the data structure looking confusing, that's because my actual code will read in data from a csv file containing many rows. So it wouldn't be easy for me to convert it to that `data` matrix you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.2" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.2" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <style>
                .menu-choice-first {
                display: inline-block;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="menu-choice-first dropdown">
            <select class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="selectNumber1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                <!-- note: title has class menu-title -->
                <div class="menu-title" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink"> </span> 
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-choice-first dropdown">
                <select class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="selectNumber2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    <!-- note: title has class menu-title -->
                    <span class="menu-title">  </span> <span class="caret"></span>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h2>
                            <label for="amount_amirol" class="control-label">Result: </label>
                        </h2>
                        <h1>
                            <input type="text" id="nm1"/> has a
                            <input type="text" id="pred" placeholder="0.00" />
                            correlation with 
                            <input type="text" id="nm2"/>          
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                var options = ['X', 'Y', 'Z'];
                var result = {
                    'XY' : 0.1,
                    'YX' : 0.1,
                    'XZ' : 0.2,
                    'ZX' : 0.2,
                    'YZ' : 0.3,
                    'ZY' : 0.3
                };

                var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber1");
                for (var i = 0,length=options.length; i < length; i++) {
                    var el2 = document.createElement("option");
                    el2.textContent = options[i];
                    el2.value = options[i];
                    select.appendChild(el2);
                }

                var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber2");
                for (var i = 0,length=options.length; i < length; i++) {
                    var el2 = document.createElement("option");
                    el2.textContent = options[i];
                    el2.value = options[i];
                    select.appendChild(el2);
                }

                $('#selectNumber1').on('change', function () {
                    $('#nm1').val($('#selectNumber1').val());
                    $('#nm2').val($('#selectNumber2').val());
                    checkCorelation();
                });
                $('#selectNumber2').on('change', function () {
                  $('#nm1').val($('#selectNumber1').val());
                    $('#nm2').val($('#selectNumber2').val());
                    checkCorelation();
                });

                function checkCorelation(){
                    $("#pred").val(result[$('#selectNumber1').val()+$('#selectNumber2').val()]);
                }
            </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```